# Can anyone help understand why its failing the test? FCC new es6 lesson "Strings using Template Literals"

Tags: javascript

I've tried multiple different configurations of the template literal. The output is correct, but it's failing the test of "includes template literal".  I feel like the test isn't right, but it's always me lol. 
Here's the link to the exercise:
https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/es6/create-strings-using-template-literals

```js
    const result = {
    success: ["max-length", "no-amd", "prefer-arrow-functions"],
    failure: ["no-var", "var-on-top", "linebreak"],
    skipped: ["id-blacklist", "no-dup-keys"]
    };
    function makeList(arr) {
    "use strict";

    // change code below this line
    const resultDisplayArray = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    resultDisplayArray.push(`<li class=\"text-warning\">${arr[i]}</li>`);
    }
    // change code above this line

    return resultDisplayArray;
    }
    /**
    * makeList(result.failure) should return:
    * [ <li class="text-warning">no-var</li>,
    *   <li class="text-warning">var-on-top</li>, 
    *   <li class="text-warning">linebreak</li> ]
    **/
    const resultDisplayArray = makeList(result.failure);
    console.log(resultDisplayArray);
```

I wish my fist post wasn't a question, but I'm just stuck. And with the new FCC format and the exercises being new, I'm having a hard time figuring out where I'm wrong.

Comment: There is no problem with your code: that is the site that expects another answer and does not get it. I'm gonna give it a try ;)

Comment: ``const resultDisplayArray = arr.map(v => `<li class="text-warning">${v}</li>`);`` works just fine, no idea what the issue is on the page though, seems an interpeter/test problem..

Comment: As anyone, I got this with the following:
  const resultDisplayArray = arr.map(v => \`<li class="text-warning">${v}</li>\`);
Their site doesn't work so well apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, their test is broken, probably using a trivial regexp that expects a single identifier not an expression in the interpolation. Changing your loop body to

```
const x = arr[i];
resultDisplayArray.push(`<li class="text-warning">${x}</li>`);
```

makes it work. Notice however that the backslash escapes for `"` need to be removed as well (to make the test pass - they are valid but unnecessary in template literals).

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easy:

```
const makeList = arr => arr.map(i => `<li class="text-warning">${i}</li>`);
```